# Install menu wrong resolution so can't continue

Tags: resolution

Using a minimal CD on a 2002 Medion laptop this happens:

Blank screen apart from a _ in the top left.
Type "cli" (text doesn't appear on screen) it eventually gets to the install menu but the resolution is wrong so most of the menu can't be seen. The laptop res is 1024x768. Any ideas?

It's a 2gig Pentium P4 with 512mg and a 20gb HD - so if anyone has any ideas about reviving it I'd be grateful. If I should just bin it then be honest...

(It's kept in a spare room for guests to use, but now XP is too dangerous now...)

Edit: it's the minimal CD version on this page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD "Ubuntu 14.04 "Trusty Tahr" Minimal CD 31MB* (MD5: a2502844750ecb6477d8fb4ff6b9aaf8, SHA1: d17c34ce716f13396040ccdc02d32482ed6b01a1)"

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please tell us what you are trying to install. Is it Ubuntu? If yes then which version? Or is it some other flavor of Ubuntu(Lubuntu, Kubuntu and the like)? If yes then again, which version of that flavor?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how long you waited, but the install process with that laptop is very slow. Try again and just let it sit. I'd say you should have some respose in about 15-20 minutes. I have the same laptop and am working on getting the resolution a little better - the display is to the left and shows a duplication of the top 1" or so of the top part of the screen on the bottom. Good luck!
PS Also try different installation method(s) like using Universal USB Installer(use Google to find) to install from USB or an expendable external hard drive(you'd want to format the hard drive during the process)
PS Ubuntu also runs VERY slow on this laptop - I think it's related to the display anomaly. I suspect it's sensing the wrong graphics hardware. Mine is still a work in progress.